# Angular test nested observable & forkjoin not working but it does on component

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, jestjs

**EDIT** The mock for `OtherService` was incorrect, The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75081624/13771772) explains pretty well what happens with the timming

---

I want to know what is wrong in the test file that make it not work like the component does. I can't figure it out why the `next:` statment from the test never gets called but it always works in the component. They both have the same code.

The thing is to understand why it happens, not to refactor the service

service:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {

  strings = ["a","b","c"]

  method():Observable<string> {
     const subject = new Subject<string>();
     let observableArray: Array<Observable<string>> = [];
    
     strings.forEach((data: strings) => {
      observableArray.push(
        this._otherService
          .returnsAnotherObservable()
          .pipe(
            tap({
              next: () => {
                console.log("next") // works in both, test & component
                subject.next(data);
              },
            })
          )
         )
    });
      forkJoin(observableArray)
        .pipe(tap(() => subject.complete()))
        .subscribe();

      return subject;
  }
}
```

component

```js
...

ngOnInit(): void {
    this._myService
      .method()
      .subscribe({
        next: (value: string) => {
          console.log(string) // it works
        },
        complete: () => {
          console.log("end")
        }
      });
  }
```

test

```js
Class MockOtherService{
   returnsAnotherObservable():Observable<any> {
       // return of(true) will not work because is not async
       return of(true).pipe(delay(1000)) // now works
   }
}

describe('MyService', () => {
  let service: MyService;
  beforeEach(async () => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [{provide: OtherService, useClass: MockOtherService }],
      imports: [AppModule]
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(MyService);
  });
   it("should work", () => {

    servie.method()
      .subscribe({
        next: (value: string) => {
          console.log("value", value) // It never reachs here
        },
        complete: () => {
          console.log("end") // it jumps directly here    
        }
    });
   });
});
```

I've tried to play with `fakeAsync` & `tick()`. I Also change the `forkJoin` to `zip` without success.

One thig that worked was changing `subject()` for `BehaviorSubject()`, because yeah, it returns everything always.. which lead me to think that the `next()` calls are happening before the test has been subscribed(if that makes sense..) but it's the same for the component.

Thank you

Comment: instead of using foreach + nested push, use `map`  right away. Free +100 for code readability

Comment: Why are you tapping into forkJoin obs instead of using subscribe?

Comment: In general why are you using another subject instead of just returning merged streams?

Comment: Hi @Antoniossss, Thanks for the reply :), a refactor for that crazy method is necessary but what I'm asking is the difference between the test and the component. They should work the same

Comment: How did you mock/stub your http calls ?

Comment: Yep, i forgot that part, I've updated the code.. I just provide MockOtherService, the console.log("next") in the service gets called always

Comment: @addUsername who knows, after all we dont know the difference between app and test - for example what is the difference betwee returnsAnotherObservable in both cases. etc.

Comment: `of(true)` is not async, http calls are on the other hand

Comment: So long story short, if you would refactor this into a sane form, you would not have such problem in the first place.

Comment: Awesome @Antoniossss!! that was the thing, the mocking was not correct, i switched it to ```return of(true).pipe(delay(1000))``` and it worked. Thanks for your help, i understand now how dangerous the code really is. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a subject of racing conditions because there is a time gap between start of forkJoin processing and you subscribing to a "result sink".

in tests your inner observables are fast (not like http calls for example, and maybe even synchronous)

```
yourMethod(){
       ///...
    
        forkJoin(observableArray)
        .pipe(tap(() => subject.complete()))
        .subscribe(); //time START, obses are HOT and doing their job
      //tick tack tick tack 
      //processing is happening, nobody is listening for the results....
      //tick tack .....
      return subject;       //tick tack tick tack ook we are returning the sink
  }

//caller

service.yourMethod() 
       //fork join already started
       //tick tack tick tack END
       .subscribe() // ok now lets subscribe to results that will come FROM NOW ON
```

but results were already drained down the pipe, just nobody listened to

Refactor that code to be a case RxJS pipeline using eg mergeAll/concatAll, dont use aditional result sink and DONT subscribe to the fork join, just return it.

As as almost single liner, doing the following can do the trick

```
return forkJoin(observableArray).pipe(
           switchMap(results=>of(...results))
       )
```

this will emit all values one by one (after observable completes). If you want results in "the real time" use `merge` instead of forkJoin

---

### **BONUS**

I have created a running example showing exactly what you have observed and how it could be done https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ve3jst?file=index.ts

```
import { of, map, Observable,forkJoin,tap,Subject,merge } from 'rxjs';

of('World')
  .pipe(map((name) => `Hello, ${name}!`))
  .subscribe(console.log);

// Open the console in the bottom right to see results.

const strings = ["a","b","c"]

function howItShouldNotBeDone():Observable<string> {
  const subject = new Subject<string>();
  let observableArray: Array<Observable<string>> = [];
 
  strings.forEach((data: string) => {
   observableArray.push(
     of("value: "+data)
       .pipe(
         tap({
           next: () => {
            //  console.log("next") // works in both, test & component
             subject.next(data);
           },
         })
       )
      )
 });
   forkJoin(observableArray)
     .pipe(tap(() => subject.complete()))
     .subscribe();

   return subject;
}

howItShouldNotBeDone().subscribe({
  next: (value: string) => {
    console.log("nah it will never happen anyway", value) // It never reachs here
  },
  complete: () => {
    console.log("how it should not be done ends") // it jumps directly here    
  }
});

function howItCouldBeDone(){
  const subject = new Subject<string>();
  let observableArray: Array<Observable<string>> = strings.map(data=>of(data))
  return merge(...observableArray)
}

howItCouldBeDone().subscribe({
  next: (value: string) => {
    console.log("Got value!", value) // It never reachs here
  },
  complete: () => {
    console.log("good code ends") // it jumps directly here    
  }
});
```

output:

```
> Hello, World!
> how it should not be done ends
> Got value! a
> Got value! b
> Got value! c
> good code ends
```

Comment: Checkout stackblitz that I have created. It shows you can wrap all that code into 3 lines. and have exactly same effect (but without the issue) :)